Cabin Air Filter Issue
I have a 2008 Honda Accord.
I recently changed cabin air filter, I bought the Bosch blue filter, and replaced this about 3 months ago, I was checking my cabin air filter because my AC was on full blast but still not getting any cold air, I found out my cabin air filter was pretty wet (there was a major storm last night) but on the side of the filter parts of it became pink, I am surprised a Bosch filter would wear out this quick.
I also may have an HVAC issue as my passenger footrest gets wet in car washes, I’ve already used air compressor on sunroof drains, and my recirculate is almost always on.
So I guess my question is, does anyone know what that pink may signify? Is it wear and tear or some kind of bacterial growth? Also, is this related to the my front passenger footrest getting soaked from car wash?

The pink on the cabin air filter I think I saw on other forum, my guess is that it’s just the foam or soap from the automatic car wash, but im still concerned as to how it’s getting in even though I have recirculate on

What color is your antifreeze? Every hvac box has a drain for ac condensate. A tube from hvac box to somewhere under the firewall allows condensation to drain to the ground. Look for it. It may be a small rubber one way valve, allowing water to drain but prevent insects from crawling in. You can poke it open with a small tool and see if its clogged; water will rush out if its blocked.

My antifreeze is blue, I’ll look into that, not too knowledgeable about it so I’d have to see if I can find that location  online

Took to mechanic, there were 2 drains by windshield where it was clogged, they cleared it and now my cabin filter doesnt get wet or the front passenger seat footrest doesnt get wet after heavy rain or carwash.

Bosch filters are really not that good, just get OEM parts only, or K&N filter. That pink is most likely some kind of bacteria or mold in your vehicle, I’d recommend you get that looked at.
Your front passenger footrest getting soaked is most definitely just the sunroof drain, the HVAC doesn’t have anything to do with it, you could probably spill water on sunroof and confirm that its leaking into footrest.

I was under the impression Bosch filters are one of the best, as they are OEM suppliers. I’ve cleaned the sunroof drain multiple time, issue persists, I think there’s a clogged drain in the hvac ac drain line or something of tbag nature, will get it checked when I get a chance
